# What is Base in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The ActiveRecord and ActionController have ::Base attached to it. I googled for this but still couldn't find an explanatory answer. I am curious to know how they exactly work.

Comment: Next to Github, you can take a look at the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for a few `::Base` classes in several modules. They're often classes that bring the basic Rails functionality to models, controllers and more when inherited from.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers, or elaborate your question if none of them answered what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You go to [GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/) and then press `t` and then type `Base`.

You will find classes like [ActiveRecord::Base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb).

Answer (score 1):

The double colon is a scope operator, and in this says that we want the class Base in the module ActionController.

```
module ActionController
  class Base
    # ... implementation
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    # ... this is a different class than ActionController::Base
  end
end

class MyController < ActionController::Base
  # class that inherits from class Base in module ActionController
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # class that inherits from class Base in module ActiveRecord
end
```